# Como atualizar funcionário especifico em tabela no MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tenho um banco de dados em SQL(banco_sql), onde existe a tabela funcionários com 4 campos (ID, FUNCIONARIO, SALARIO, DEPARTAMENTO).

```
ID        FUNCIONARIO        SALARIO        DEPARTAMENTO 
1         Pedro              1400           TI
2         Isabela            2500           Juridico
3         Guilherme          1700           TI
4         José               1800           Marketing  
5         João               2200           Juridico
6         Pedro              1300           Marketing
```

Gostaria de saber como atualizar um determinado dado (ex: Salario), de determinado funcionário?

Comment: Só uma dica mysql-workbench é uma ferramenta de modelagem, a sua questão é com produção, ou seja apenas mysql, por isso editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 15):

A resposta é muito simples: você só precisa fazer um *update* na tabela `funcionarios` e colocar o ID da pessoas cujo salário será editado.

Exemplo:

```
UPDATE NOME_DA_TABELA 
SET CAMPO_QUE_SERÀ_EDITADO = NOVO_VALOR 
WHERE ID = 'ID_DA_PESSOA';
```

Depois para visualizar seus dados basta fazer um *select*:

```
SELECT * FROM NOME_DA_TABELA;
```